# How do you figure out the values of a lookup table based on the CRC polynomial?

Tags: crc16

In this code http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/51data/CRC16.java, the program uses a lookup table based on the crc polynomial 1 + x^2 + x^15 + x^16. My question is how do you figure out the values of the lookup table based on the crc polynomial. Otherwise how can you make a lookup table by yourself for any given crc polynomial? An example you could use would be what is the lookup table for the crc polynomial of x15+x13+ x6+x4+x1+1?

Answer (score 1):

Each entry in the lookup table is the CRC of the single byte that is the index of that entry.